# Using NSOpenPanel and copying selected file - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsfilemanager, nsopenpanel

I'm trying to create an app that will copy the selected sound file to the app's directory. To do it, I've written the following code :

```
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
[openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aif",@"aiff",@"mp3",@"wav",@"m4a",nil]];

if ( [openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    NSString *dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSLog(@"Datapath is %@", dataPath);
    NSLog(@"Selected Files : %@",[[openDlg URLs] objectAtIndex:0]);
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath] == NO)
    {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[[openDlg URLs] objectAtIndex:0] toPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] error:&error];
        NSLog(@"File copied");

    }
}
```

The problems are that I can select each types of files (not only aif, wav, mp3 etc.) and I never get `File copied`. Although, the paths are correct. When I delete the if statement, I get an error saying : `[NSURL fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1005a0b90`.
What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an `NSURL` to an API that expects a path in an `NSString`.  You might consider using the URL-based API:

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtURL:(NSURL *)srcURL toURL:(NSURL *)dstURL error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

Like this:

```
[fileManager copyItemAtURL: [[openDlg URLs] objectAtIndex:0] toURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]] error:&error];
```

Also, I'm guessing that the file has already been copied to the bundle since your description indicates that `[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]` is returning `NO` (since your NSLog is never executed.) You can either check that manually, or you can ask the `NSFileManager` to delete any existing file before copying in a newly selected file.